# Memory Error on Lists in Spreadsheet View

Tags: 2007, list, datasheet

I have a list in SharePoint 2007 with about 187 items and in the Data View, several of our users are experiencing this error:

> **The Instruction at "0x3271fe85" referenced memory at "0x00000000".  The memory cannot be read.**

This appears to work in IE6 for one user, and IE8 for another.  However, there are two users that get this error in IE8.

Comment: How many items are in the list, and how many are you bringing back in the data view?

Comment: @James, updated question above.  I actually thought the list was bigger, but it's only 187 items.

Comment: Right, and what version number of 2007 do you have? (SP1? SP2?)

Comment: @James, we're using SP2.  Also, thanks for your interest with this question.

Comment: Cool, finally, what version of Office do you guys have installed, and are you all patched and up to date?

Comment: Are there any addons your users have installed?  Custome toolbars, etc...

Comment: @James: we're running Office 2007 MSO (12.0.6514.5001).  @Serious SharePoint: no custom/costume toolbars (although that is a good idea for this years' Halloween :)

Comment: It doesn't look like your client configuration are the same, what are the specs on the machines?  I've seen memory issues with client machines when they only have 1-2GB of memory.  Are there any other errors on the machine (secuirty, system, or app logs) that are happening at the same time?  Is IE the only thing running when they get the error?

Comment: Thanks, Jesus! +1:) Yes, the client machines only have 1-2GB of memory.  We haven't seen anything come up on the server, as we believe the error is on the client.  Good question though.  Also, see my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the users (including myself) had a gov machines with a *specific* install of Microsoft Office 2003.  I ran the **repair** option from the Uninstall dialog and haven't seen this error since this post.

Will keep you posted if it comes back.